# Magento2: How to check if request is from Web Service?

Tags: magento2, http-request, webapi

In Magento 1, We used to check as:

```
if (Mage::getSingleton('api/server')->getAdapter() != null) {
    // request from Web-Service
}
```

How to check the same in Magento2?

I didn't find any proper adapter which fits for both REST & SOAP.

Comment: are you looking for observer?

Comment: Mostly this will be checked from Observer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I used `Magento\Framework\App\State::getAreaCode()` to find if request is coming via SOAP / REST API.

You can check the possible area codes in `Magento\Framework\App\Area` class.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar task once, and if I remember correctly I did this by checking if `\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http::getFullActionName()` equals `__`. I don't know why, but for REST requests this would be the full action name.

However, I did not find this safe at the time because it didn't feel like the most correct solution, so I ended up by strictly checking the request string:

```
if (
    $this->request->getRequestString() === '/rest/V1/carts/mine/payment-information'
) {
    ...
```

As you might have guessed, in my situation I had to check if the current REST request was a very specific one.

I don't know about SOAP, but I'm assuming you could use a similar approach. However, it still does not quite feel like the proper solution.

Comment: Yeah. This won't help me :(

Answer (score 1):

Please check with below code,

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
    $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
}

$isApirequest = $controller->getRequest()->getControllerModule() == 'Mage_Api';
if ($isApirequest) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: But here the problem is: there are some REST APIs which are called from the website also.