# How to extend rest API request or check request from web or rest API?

Tags: magento2, module, checkout, payment-methods, onestepcheckout

I have created a module for checkout payment methods event.
But I need to check request is getting from web or rest API.

I mean something like:

```
if(request from rest API)
{ 
    echo "REST API"; 
} 
else 
{ 
    echo "WEB";
}
```

Please Help me

Comment: Why do you want to distinct these two?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Magento\Framework\App\State::getAreadCode()` to check the request is from web or API. If the request is from API, this will return "webapi_rest" or "webapi_soap". If the request is from web, this will return "frontend".

Ref: [Magento2: How to check if request is from Web Service?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/162527/magento2-how-to-check-if-request-is-from-web-service)

Comment: can you help to find out rest api get products 404 page error : https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/246597/57334 @PY Yick